# How to make Primeng chart legend's color panel as circular?

Tags: angular, charts, primeng

Currently I have this chart option,

```
this.chartOptions = {
  legend: { position: "bottom" },
  usePointStyle:true
};
```

and chart data

```
this.chartData = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: ['#BFC9CA', '#E1D03B', '#9BBB59', '#00B0F0', '#8064A2', '#FF8C00'],
      pointStyle: 'circle'
    }
  ]
};
```

How to create a circular color label which will be displayed in the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by the "color panel".

You could specify `pointerStyle: true` in [`labels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) configuration.

```
legend: {
  display: true,
  position: 'bottom',
  labels: {
    fontColor: "#000080",
    usePointStyle: true
  },
},
```

And specify one of the [pointer styles](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements#point-styles) in the `datasets` property.

```
datasets: [{
  .
  .
  pointStyle: 'circle',
}]
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-ahzlek)

Comment: First a question. Is this the result you are looking for? A circular representation of color instead of a rectangle in the legend, but for a pie chart?

Comment: Yes @Michael D, I added the same chart option as you have provided in your answer.. It worked